# New to Lambda Expression how to convert from one type to another type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I'm trying to return a list of countries, and assigning the return values to CountryCode and CountryName, I keep getting these errors:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

and

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Here is my code:

```
public class CountryViewModel
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }


    /*SELECT COUNTRIES */

    public static IQueryable<CountryViewModel> GetCountries()
    {
        DbEntities _context = new DbEntities();

        var featureCode = "PCLI";

        var countries = _context.country
                        .Where(c => c.Feature_Code == featureCode
                        .Select(n => new CountryViewModel
                        {
                            CountryCode = c.Country_Code,
                            CountryName = c.Name
                        }
                        ));

        return countries;
```

}

I couldn't find a proper example to help me along with this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code could not possibly compile, and furthermore, I think what has been elided is extremely relevent.  (i.e.  probably a call to `.ToList()`)

Comment: ^ above is important to note; the code you've provided wouldn't have a List anywhere (except for if that's what _context.country is; if so, that shouldn't be a List).  As the second error: what's the type of c.Feature_code?

Comment: What is your data type for Feature_Code of your class country??

Comment: Well, it doesn't that's why I'm looking for help, as for the type Feature_Code is varchar(10), I've tried .ToList() and didn't help.  But thanks for your comment anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closing ")" for the .Where clause should be after "featureCode", just before .Select.  The error message sounds like it's assuming the Select clause is to be part of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

In you example the variable 'countries' you are returning is an IEnumerable not the IQueryable you have prototyped.  I suppose you could return countries.AsQueryable().  If you want to return a list then return countries.ToList().

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few things wrong with your code as far as I can see. Also I'm assuming `DbEntities` implements `IDisposable` so you should probably wrap that in a `using` statement.

```
public class CountryViewModel
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public static IQueryable<CountryViewModel> GetCountries()
    {
        using (DbEntities _context = new DbEntities())
        {
            var featureCode = "PCLI";

            var countries = _context.country
                .Where(c => c.Feature_Code == featureCode)
                .Select(c => new CountryViewModel
                {
                    CountryCode = c.Country_Code,
                    CountryName = c.Name
                }
            );

            return countries;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Ninject so I didn't need the using statement.  But the rest of your suggestion worked for me, thanks for your help man.